# Unique event != Sessions?

Tags: google-analytics, tags, analytics, google-tag-manager

My single page app have a x page which is accessible only by a button in the y page.

The unique event should then correspond to the same amount of session of this web page.

y Page > Session > Click on button > Same session on the x subdomain?
The sub domain is correctly linked via the single page app config.

But is not the case, why?

Thanks in advance,

Edit : The sessions are only via paid search. Direct sessions are not included in the figures.

Answer (score 0):

Because people can click on your CTA, open the x subdomain, wait for 30 minutes until their session dies, then reload the page? Now you have one click and two pageviews there.

And there are many more ways to do it. For example, click the CTA, but then close the x subdomain page before it loads completely? Now you have a click without the pageview.

Anyway, there can be many situations explaining the discrepancies in data, so you should definitely narrow down your request by adding some details and outlining debugging that you've tried to answer the question on your own.

Comment: Paid search on y page = 3000 sessions / Click on button on y page= 300 / Session on subdomain = 700 / Yep your explanation is possible but such a difference between click on cta and sessions makes me wonder

Comment: yes, this difference indicates that people/bots are getting to your subdomain through a different route. I would suggest looking at the data and trying to find answers there.

Comment: The sessions are only via paid search. Direct sessions are not included in the figures.
If the user clicks on the CTA, goes to the subdomain, leaves and comes back 30 min later via direct, is it counted on the sessions via paid search?

Comment: I think so. Direct is not allowed to overwrite paid, but it would likely depend on the attribution model.